# "I hesitated to ask." So did I ask or not ask?

Tags: expressions

"I hesitated to ask Question X" seems to mean that I hesitated, and then I asked Question X. Often though, the expression seems to imply that I, in fact, never asked Question X.

Here are a few examples (via ludwig.guru). In each case, do you think the question was asked, or not?

"There was a last question I had hesitated to ask: Why, given her history, did she risk remarriage?" - Judith Thurman, The New Yorker

"On previous meetings, I had hesitated to ask the obvious question — Why did you stop writing?" - Alejandro Chacoff, The New Yorker

"Not wanting to appear naïve -- as if I could have appeared otherwise -- I hesitated to ask questions." - The New York Times, Travel

Comment: There is no way to tell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't tell. It means that they were reluctant to ask, but whether they actually asked eventually is unclear.

For your second quote:

> "On previous meetings, I had hesitated to ask the obvious question — Why did you stop writing?"

it's clear that he didn't ask on previous meetings, because if he had asked the question on the first meeting, he wouldn't have needed to worry about asking it on the subsequent ones.

For your first quote,

> "There was a last question I had hesitated to ask: Why, given her history, did she risk remarriage?"

you can tell that she eventually asked the question, because *had hesitated* puts the hesitation in the past. But because she had hesitated to ask it, that was the last question she asked.

For your last quote,

> "Not wanting to appear naïve — as if I could have appeared otherwise — I hesitated to ask questions."

you can't tell.

Answer (score -1):

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hesitate) gives the following definition comparing synonyms. Hesitate generally implies that the action is finally taken:

> Hesitate, Waver, Vacillate, Falter mean to show irresolution or uncertainty.
>
> ***HESITATE implies a pause before deciding or acting or choosing.***
>
> - *hesitated before answering the question*.
>
> ***Waver*** implies hesitation after seeming to decide and so connotes weakness or a retreat. *Wavered in his support of the rebels*.
>
> ***Vacillate*** implies prolonged hesitation from inability to reach a firm decision. vacillated until events were out of control.
>
> ***Falter*** implies a wavering or stumbling and often connotes nervousness, lack of courage, or outright fear. never once faltered during her testimony.

Comment: "*HESITATE implies a pause before deciding or acting or choosing.*" But it does NOT imply what the decision/act/choice was at the end.

Answer (score -1):

Definitely, '***DIDN'T ASK.***'

According to Merriam-Webster's Dictionary:

***HESITATE***

transitive verb

: to hold back from (doing or saying something) in doubt or uncertainty

// Don't hesitate to call if you need something

Comment: "*Definitely, 'DIDN'T ASK.'*" Didn't ask **while hesitating**. Doesn't say anything about what happened **after** the hesitation was over.